# Всплывающее уведомление

Tags: php, javascript

У меня есть кнопка, на которой вести функция: `<div class="btn btn-v-1" style="margin-top:30px" type="text" onclick='SaveCountry();'>Upload</div>`
Как сделать, чтоб если функция отработала успешно - по центру экрана высвечивалось сообщение "Success" и через секунду меня перебрасывало на другую страницу?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на **JavaScript**:

Если функция **someFunc** отработает то вы увидите текст `SUCCESS` также через секунду перенаправитесь на *Stackoverflow*

```js
someFunc = _ => console.info("worked");
someFunc();

if(someFunc){ //Если функция someFunc равен true  то будет показано SUCCESS также вы перенаправитесь на Stackoverflow через секунду
    document.write("<h1 class='success'>SUCCESS</h1>");
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.replace('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/');
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.success {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Думаю можно просто alert и не парится)
document.write-то удаляет всё из страницы, верно?)

Comment: Если document.write вызвать во время загрузки страницы - выполняется нормально. Если вызвать после того как страница загрузилась - оно очищает страницу. Вот попробуйте прямо сейчас зайти в консоль и напечатать document.write("Hello")